# Installing Ubuntu, Windows 10 not in grub now

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

Long story short I was installing Ubuntu on my computer and have been wrestling with it to try to get it to install on the second hard drive. The first error was with uefi. It said that:

> This machine's firmware has started the installer in UEFI mode but it looks like there may be existing operating systems already installed using "BIOS compatibility mode". If you continue to install Debian in UEFI mode, it might be difficult to reboot the machine into any BIOS-mode operating systems later.
>   If you wish to install in UEFI mode and don't care about keeping the ability to boot one of the existing systems, you have the option to force that here. If you wish to keep the option to boot an existing operating system, you should choose NOT to force UEFI installation here.")

I chose not to force it

Then during the first attempt there was an error that forced me to quit the installer and when I came back the installer told me that Ubuntu and Windows 10 were both installed, so I chose to repair the Ubuntu installation. Now, however, Windows 10 does not appear when I boot up, and when I tell the comp to boot from the drive it is on from the bios it boots up grub (which doesn't see it).

I have no idea how to get it to be in the boot menu or to get it to appear. When I checked to see the partitions on the first drive it told me that it exited with status 14, Windows is hibernated, refused to mount. The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting)

I have no idea if I really messed up and ended up deleting Windows 10 or if something else is wrong. Please help.

Comment: Found another person with the same issue but no awnsers. They were told to find boot info. Mine is at http://paste2.org/eN7ny4Lm

Answer (score 0):

I used a windows 10 instilation disk to enter windows 10 and the entering the command prompt (shift f10) used the commands

> bootrec.exe /fixboot
>
> bootrec.exe /fixmbr

to reinstall the windows bootloader. A program titled easyBDC was than used to add Ubuntu back as an option. Its not a perfect solution as Windows 10 does still not appear in grub, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

In ubuntu, update grub with `sudo update-grub`.
If the boot files of windows are still intact, it will be scanned and would be added to the bootup list.

> The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting)

To solve this problem, simply press `Shift` key while shutting down windows which will perform a proper shutdown instead of a fast-shutdown.

Hope this helps someone!